# Delete all selected table rows with ZK

Tags: java, zk

I have a ZK grid in which I generate random numbers on each row. Each row is made up of a checkbox and the number itself.

I wanted to have a button that deletes all the rows with checked checkboxes. Here is the event handler for the 'delete' button:

```
deleteButton.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK,
            new EventListener() {

        public void onEvent(Event evt) {
                Iterator<Component> selected = randomTable.queryAll("row checkbox").iterator();
                System.out.println("Deleted: ");
                while (selected.hasNext()) {
                    Checkbox c = (Checkbox) selected.next();
                    if (c.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.print(c.getId()); 
                        System.out.println(" from row " + c.getParent().getId());
                        c.getParent().detach(); // detach the checked row
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

But it deletes only the first checked row, even though it finds all the other checked ones.

I'm still new to ZK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. Turns out that If I use an intermediary list to store the rows I want to remove, `detach()` works on all of them.

Anyway, feel free to share any hints as to why it did not work in the first place. +1 for any contribution.

Here's the updated code:

```
deleteButton.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK,
            new EventListener() {
        public void onEvent(Event evt) {
            List<Component> toRemove = new Vector<Component>();
            Iterator<Component> selected = randomTable.queryAll("row checkbox").iterator();
            System.out.println("Deleted: ");
            while (selected.hasNext()) {
                Checkbox c = (Checkbox) selected.next();
                if (c.isChecked()) {
                    System.out.print(c.getId()); 
                    System.out.println(" from row " + c.getParent().getId());
                    toRemove.add(c.getParent());
                }
            }
            for (Component c : toRemove)
                c.detach();
        }

    });
```